# How to bind method in MenuFlyout with Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, contextmenu, caliburn.micro

I want to learn Caliburn Micro for use it in my Windows Phone application.
I don't know how to use Caliburn Micro in my MenuFlyoutItem.
I have tried in this way:

```
<StackPanel micro:Message.Attach="[Event Holding] = [Action OpenFlyout($source)]">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit" micro:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action EditEle($source)]"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Remove"  micro:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action DelEle($source)]" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

"OpenFlyout" works. So when i tap and hold an element I can view the MenuFlyout.
But, if i click on "Edit", the application crashes.

I have tried to insert a breakpoint into the function but the application didn't stop.
So, i think that there is a binding problem.

The methods DelEle and EditEle are very similiar (except for their tasks).
Here you can find the method: DelEle.

```
public void DelEle(FrameworkElement senderElement)
{
    CreditCard obj = senderElement.DataContext as CreditCard;
    DeleteFromCardKeyList(obj.NameID.ToUpper());
    DeleteTxtCardFile(obj.NameID.ToUpper());
    CreditCards.Remove(obj);
}
```

Sorry for my poor English. Thanks for your help.

Comment: $eventArgs wouldn't be a better solution? Are you able to debug the DelEle() method to see if it crashes before that? or in that method?  There is the possibility that you are running into a Visual Tree issue.  <MenuFlyOut cm:Model.Bind="{Binding}"></MenuFlyOut> try this as well

Comment: I have tried " <MenuFlyout micro:Bind.Model="{Binding}">" but nothing has changed. And no, i can't debug DelEle bacause App Crashes first.
I think is a XAML problem, if i bind the element with another method it crashes the same.

Comment: Hello everyone. I resolve my problem follow this tutorial: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/first-steps-in-caliburn-micro-with-windows-phone-8-how-to-manage-different-datacontext/
Thanks to All.

First of all: I set a name to my page (x:Name="MainP").
After it i've changed my XAML in this way.

'<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Modifica"                                    micro:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ElementName=MainP, Path=DataContext}"                                                micro:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action EditEle($dataContext)]"/>'

Comment: yeah that was next in the trouble shooting direction was to go with TargetWithoutContext.

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
caliburn:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=DataContext,ElementName=stackpanelName}"
```